# Getting rid of Double quotes within a value using JQ

Tags: bash, jq

I am trying to create a `--data-raw` with the help of `jq` , it works fine for the most part, except where i have a list .

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST="'bfc', 'punch', 'mld', 'extended_mld', 'chargingstation', 'ch'"
BFC_TAG=$BUILD_ID
UPLOAD_TO=s3
COMPILE=$test
REGION=world
PROJECT=bfc
JSON_STRING=$( jq -n \
--arg a "$BFC_TAG" \
--arg b "$UPLOAD_TO" \
--arg c "$TEST" \
--arg d "$REGION" \
--arg f "$PROJECT" '
{brfc_tag: $a,
upload_to: $b,
compile: [ $c ],
region: $d,
project: $f
}')
echo ${JSON_STRING}
```

Output:

```
{ "bfc_tag": "", "upload_to": "s3", "compile": [ "'bfc', 'punch', 'mld', 'extended_mld', 'chargingstation', 'ch'" ], "region": "world", "project": "bfc" }
```

If u look at the output particularly in `compile` key it has " in beginning and in the end, which break breaks python code, which consumes this, i need to get rid of the double quotes within compile, any help aprreaciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `TEST` as scalar type, if you are intending to store multiple values in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those single quotes are already present in your input string:

```sh
TEST="'bfc', 'punch', 'mld', 'extended_mld', 'chargingstation', 'ch'"
```

I would recommend removing those, and creating a simple csv witch JQ can [split](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example60) for us

```sh
TEST="bfc,punch,mld,extended_mld,chargingstation,ch"
```

To create an array from that string, use;

```
compile: $c | split(",")
```

So the complete code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
TEST="bfc,punch,mld,extended_mld,chargingstation,ch"
BFC_TAG=$BUILD_ID
UPLOAD_TO=s3
COMPILE=$test
REGION=world
PROJECT=bfc
JSON_STRING=$( jq -n \
--arg a "$BFC_TAG" \
--arg b "$UPLOAD_TO" \
--arg c "$TEST" \
--arg d "$REGION" \
--arg f "$PROJECT" '
{brfc_tag: $a,
upload_to: $b,
compile: $c | split(","),
region: $d,
project: $f
}')
echo ${JSON_STRING}
```

Will produce:

```json
{ "brfc_tag": "", "upload_to": "s3", "compile": [ "bfc", "punch", "mld", "extended_mld", "chargingstation", "ch" ], "region": "world", "project": "bfc" }
```

Comment: Seems to work like a charm, i did not knew we can use split here in bash as well, thanks a ton

Comment: The `split` is from JQ itself: [See the docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example60) for more info!